# Move up character displayed inline

Tags: css, layout, positioning

I have the following markup for breadcrumbs menu:

```
<div>
    <span class="start-here">You are here:<span>
    <a href="/">example.com</a>
    <span class="raquo"> › </span> 
    <a href="/news">News</a>
    <span class="raquo"> › </span> 
    Title
</div>
```

Is there a smart way to move those `›`  (`.raquo`) characters a few pixels up without absolute positioning when all of the elements are displayed inline? I want this character to be smaller than the others and to be displayed in the center of the line (or some pixels down/up).

(I need it to work also for IE6 and up)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure about IE6, but it seems like the following should get you close to what you want.

```
.raquo {
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

Just make `font-size` whatever you need, vertical align should set it to the middle of the `line-height`.

Comment: Better off setting the font size to `0.5em` (for instance), then it will adjust itself to changes to the default font size.

Answer (score 80):

```
.raquo {
    position:relative;
    top:-2px;
}
```

worked best for me

Comment: My recommendation would be to set top to `-0.1em` (for instance), so that it still works if you ever change the font-size.

Answer (score 12):

```css
vertical-align: 3px
```

with any amount or unit.

It is very powerful for things like custom fonts and other spans and elements that are incorrectly justified. I just used it on a font that I got from my designer.

Comment: This was the only that worked for me to get a uikit icon to move up by a few px.

Answer (score 4):

Building on @sashn's answer, if you want to future-proof it against future font size changes, I would do this...

```
.raquo {
  position:relative;
  top:-0.1em;
}
```

This way the position offset will automatically shrink or expand depending on font size.

Comment: Good tip - this worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vertical-align:top; font-size:x-small;` in CSS. It's hard to get perfectly in the middle though...

Answer (score -4):

I hate to say this... but you could use a `table`. I've found it to be the only reliable way to make sure that everything is vertically centered in a line:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="start-here">You are here:<td>
    <td><a href="/">example.com</a></td>
    <td class="raquo"> › </td> 
    <td><a href="/news">News</a></td>
    <td class="raquo"> › </td> 
    <td>Title</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```